# How to interpolate using in polar coordinate

Tags: matlab, interpolation, polar-coordinates

I have polar coordinates, radius `0.05 <= r <= 1` and `0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π`. The radius `r` is 50 values between 0.05 to 1, and polar angle θ is 24 values between 0 to 2π.

How do I interpolate `r = 0.075` and `theta = pi/8`?

Comment: @rahnema1 OP said [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system); you are thinking of [cylindrical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system).

Comment: Have you tried `interp1`?

Comment: Is there a relation between `r` and `θ`?

Comment: @rahnema1 but you're right, as posed, it would seem the OP has another data dimension, beit color or `z` values.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yeah without z it it unknown what should be interpolated!?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis ya I tried interp1 and interp2 but its not work for polar coordinate and works for Cartesian coordinate

Comment: @rahnema1 z is z(r,t) it is 50X24 matrix

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis there is no relation between r and theta

Comment: are each one of r or theta sorted?

Comment: @rahnema yes...

Comment: @rahnema1 what would be interpolated: if you have (`r`, `θ`) data, and you want to find intermediate points (see `polarplot` for examples). The OP  has cylindrical coordinates, however.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis the correct way is to convert polar to rectangular and as you said scattered data should be interpolated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments you have the following information

```
%the test point
ri=0.53224;
ti = pi/8;

%formula fo generation of Z
g=9.81
z0=@(r)0.01*(g^2)*((2*pi)^-4)*(r.^-5).*exp(-1.25*(r/0.3).^-4);
D=@(t)(2/pi)*cos(t).^2; 
z2=@(r,t)z0(r).*D(t) ;

%range of vlaues of r and theta
r=[0.05,0.071175,0.10132,0.14422,0.2053, 0.29225,0.41602,0.5922,0.84299,1.2]; 
t=[0,0.62832,1.2566,1.885, 2.5133,3.1416,3.7699,4.3982,5.0265,5.6549,6.2832];
```

and you want interplation of the test point.

When you sample some data to use them for interpolation you should consider how to sample data according to your requirements.
So when you are sampling a regular grid of polar coordinates ,those coordinates when converted to rectangular will form a circular shape that
most of the points are concentrated in the center of the cricle and when we move from the center to outer regions distance between the points increased.

```
%regular grid generated for r and t
[THETA R] = meshgrid(t ,r);
% Z for polar grid
Z=z2(R,THETA);
%convert coordinate from polar to cartesian(rectangular):
[X, Y] = pol2cart (THETA, R);
%plot points
plot(X, Y, 'k.');
axis equal
```

[image]

So when you use those point for interpolation the accuracy of the interpolation is greater in the center and lower in the outer regions where the distance between points increased.
In the other word with this sampling method you place more importance on the center region related to outer ones.
To increase accuracy density of grid points (r and theta) should be increased so if length of r and theta is 11 you can create r and theta with size 20 to increase accuracy.
In the other hand if you create a regular grid in *rectangular coordinates* an equal importance is given to each region . So accuracy of the interpolation will be the same in all regions.
For it first you create a regular grid in the polar coordinates then convert the grid to rectangular coordinates so you can calculate the extents (min max) of the sampling points in the rectangular coordinates. Based on this extents you can create a regular grid in the rectangular coordinates
Regular grid of rectangular coordinates then converted to polar coordinated to get z for grid points using z2 formula.

```
%get the extent of points
extentX = [min(X(:)) max(X(:))];
extentY = [min(Y(:)) max(Y(:))];

%sample 100 points(or more or less) inside a region specified be the extents
X_samples = linspace(extentX(1),extentX(2),100);
Y_samples = linspace(extentY(1),extentY(2),100);
%create regular grid in rectangular coordinates
[XX YY] = meshgrid(X_samples, Y_samples);
[TT RR] = cart2pol(XX,YY);
Z_rect = z2(RR,TT);
```

For interpolation of a test point say `[ri ti]` first it converted to rectangular then using `XX ,YY` value of `z` is interpolated

```
[xi yi] = pol2cart (ti, ri);
z=interp2(XX,YY,Z_rect,xi,yi);
```

If you have no choice to change how you sample the data and only have a grid of polar points as discussed with @RodyOldenhuis you can do the following:

1. Interpolate polar coordinates with `interp2` (interpolation for gridded data)
   this approach is straightforward but has the shortcoming that `r` and theta are not of the same scale and this may affect the accuracy of the interpolation.

   `z = interp2(THETA, R, Z, ti, ri)`
2. convert polar coordinates to rectangular and then apply an interpolation method that is for scattered data.
   this approach requires more computations but result of it is more reliable.
   MATLAB has `griddata` function that given scattered points first generates a triangulation of points and then creates a regular grid on top of the triangles and interpolates values of grid points.
   So if you want to interpolate value of point `[ri ti]` you should then apply a second interpolation to get value of the point from the interpolated grid.

With the help of some information from [spatialanalysisonline](http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/HTML/triangulation_with_linear_inte.htm)  and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)  linear interpolation based on triangulation calculated this way (tested in Octave. In newer versions of MATLAB use of `triangulation` and `pointLocation` recommended instead of `delaunay` and `tsearch` ):

```
ri=0.53224;
ti = pi/8;
[THETA R] = meshgrid(t ,r);
[X, Y] = pol2cart (THETA, R);
[xi yi] = pol2cart (ti, ri);
%generate triangulation
tri = delaunay (X, Y);
%find the triangle that contains the test point
idx = tsearch (X, Y, tri, xi, yi);
pts= tri(idx,:);
%create a matrix that repesents equation of a plane (triangle) given its 3 points
m=[X(pts);Y(pts);Z(pts);ones(1,3)].';
%calculate z based on det(m)=0;
z= (-xi*det(m(:,2:end)) + yi*det([m(:,1) m(:,3:end)]) + det(m(:,1:end-1)))/det([m(:,1:2) m(:,end)]);
```

**More refinement:**
Since it is known that the search point is surrounded by 4 points we can use only those point for triangulation. these points form a trapezoid. Each diagonal of trapezoid forms two triangles so using vertices of the trapezoid we can form 4 triangles, also a point inside a trapezoid can lie in at least 2 triangles.
the previous method based on triangulation only uses information from one triangle but here z of the test point can be interpolated two times from data of two triangles and the calculated z values can be averaged to get a better approximation.

```
%find 4 points surrounding the test point
ft= find(t<=ti,1,'last');
fr= find(cos(abs(diff(t(ft+(0:1))))/2) .* r < ri,1,'last');
[T4 R4] = meshgrid(t(ft+(0:1)), r(fr+(0:1)));
[X4, Y4] = pol2cart (T4, R4);
Z4 = Z(fr+(0:1),ft+(0:1));
%form 4 triangles
tri2= nchoosek(1:4,3);
%empty vector of z values that will be interpolated from 4 triangles
zv = NaN(4,1);
for h = 1:4
    pts = tri2(h,:);
    % test if the point lies in the triangle
    if ~isnan(tsearch(X4(:),Y4(:),pts,xi,yi))
        m=[X4(pts) ;Y4(pts) ;Z4(pts); [1 1 1]].';
        zv(h)= (-xi*det(m(:,2:end)) + yi*det([m(:,1) m(:,3:end)]) + det(m(:,1:end-1)))/det([m(:,1:2) m(:,end)]);
    end
end
z= mean(zv(~isnan(zv)))
```

**Result:**

```
True z: 
(0.0069246)
Linear Interpolation of (Gridded) Polar Coordinates : 
(0.0085741)
Linear Interpolation with Triangulation of Rectangular Coordinates: 
(0.0073774 or 0.0060992)  based on triangulation
Linear Interpolation with Triangulation of Rectangular Coordinates(average):
(0.0067383)
```

**Conclusion**:

Result of interpolation related to structure of original data and the sampling method. If the sampling method matches pattern of original data result of interpolation is more accurate, so in cases that grid points of polar coordinates follow pattern of data result of interpolation of regular polar coordinate can be more reliable. But if regular polar coordinates do not match the structure of data or structure of data is such as an irregular terrain, method of interpolation based on triangulation can better represent the data.

Comment: this is correct way to interpolate using the functions z(r) and D(t) but my question is how  to interpolate using data sets (z(r,t))

Comment: there is no difference instead of writing `Z = z2(R,THETA)` you can write `Z =[......]` that `[....]` indicates your data set

Comment: clc
clear all
%the test point
ri=0.53224;
ti = pi/8;
tt1=xlsread('2d_inpdata.xlsx');
%formula fo generation of Z
g=9.81;
% z0=@(r)0.01*(g^2)*((2*pi)^-4)*(r.^-5).*exp(-1.25*(r/0.3).^-4);
% D=@(t)(2/pi)*cos(t).^2; 
% z2=@(r,t)z0(r).*D(t) ;

%range of vlaues of r and theta
r=[0.05,0.071175,0.10132,0.14422,0.2053, 0.29225,0.41602,0.5922,0.84299,1.2]; 
t=[0,0.62832,1.2566,1.885, 2.5133,3.1416,3.7699,4.3982,5.0265,5.6549,6.2832];

%regular grid generated for r and t
[THETA R] = meshgrid(t ,r);
% Z for polar grid
% Z=z2(R,THETA);

Comment: %convert coordinate from polar to cartesian(rectangular):
[X, Y] = pol2cart (THETA, R);
[xi yi] = pol2cart (ti, ri);
z=interp2(r,t,tt1',ri,ti);

Comment: tt1 is 10X11 matrix i get  0.0086 instead of 0.0067

Comment: you are using `Linear Interpolation of (Gridded) Polar Coordinates` if you see the answer the same result appears. you should use method `Linear Interpolation with Triangulation of Rectangular Coordinates(average):`

Comment: I tried with 2D data (without using functions), but am not getting the exact value

Comment: I need the exact value with out using this functions (z0=@(r)0.01*(g^2)*((2*pi)^-4)*(r.^-5).*exp(-1.25*(r/0.3).^-4);
D=@(t)(2/pi)*cos(t).^2; 
z2=@(r,t)z0(r).*D(t) ;)

Comment: %the test point
ri=0.53224;
ti = pi/8;
tt1=xlsread('gam3p3_2d_inpdata.xlsx');
%formula fo generation of Z
g=9.81;
z0=@(r)0.01*(g^2)*((2*pi)^-4)*(r.^-5).*exp(-1.25*(r/0.3).^-4);
D=@(t)(2/pi)*cos(t).^2; 
z2=@(r,t)z0(r).*D(t) ;

%range of vlaues of r and theta
r=[0.05,0.071175,0.10132,0.14422,0.2053, 0.29225,0.41602,0.5922,0.84299,1.2]; 
t=[0,0.62832,1.2566,1.885, 2.5133,3.1416,3.7699,4.3982,5.0265,5.6549,6.2832];
%regular grid generated for r and t
[THETA R] = meshgrid(t ,r);
% Z for polar grid
Z=tt1;%z2(R,THETA);

Comment: %convert coordinate from polar to cartesian(rectangular):
[X, Y] = pol2cart (THETA, R);interpn(t,r,tt1',ti,ri,'spline');

Comment: %get the extent of points
extentX = [min(X(:)) max(X(:))];
extentY = [min(Y(:)) max(Y(:))];

%sample 100 points(or more or less) inside a region specified be the extents
X_samples = linspace(extentX(1),extentX(2),100);
Y_samples = linspace(extentY(1),extentY(2),100);
%create regular grid in rectangular coordinates
[XX YY] = meshgrid(X_samples, Y_samples);
[TT RR] = cart2pol(XX,YY);
Z_rect = z2(RR,TT);

[xi yi] = pol2cart (ti, ri);
z=interp2(X_samples,Y_samples,Z_rect,xi,yi)

Comment: when i used interpn (with using 2d data points) i got wrong answer but when i using with formula i got correct answer.  i need to use with 2d data points

Comment: That is also wrong, I tried in octave but i get answer for particular one input (ti,ri) only, not other input values

Comment: for multiple input you can use `for loop`

Comment: no am not telling like that but for other input values is not match with formulas

Comment: I can not guess why result doesn't match maybe due to wrong input

Comment: I found that problem, the problem is while using condition statement for the formula, the output will get wrong, but without using condition statement for the same formula, i will get correct output. I'll give example

Comment: clc
clear all
% Coordinates
r = linspace(0.05, 1.2, 10);
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 8);
% Some synthetic data
% z = g^2*r.^3'*cos(t/2);%sort(rand(50, 24));
z=zeros();
for i=1:10
    for j=1:8
if r(i)<0.5||r(i)>1
    z(i,j)=0;
else
z(i,j) = r(i).^3'*cos(t(j)/2);
end
    end
end

% Values of interest
ri = 0.5;
ti = pi/18;
% exact value
z1 = ri.^3'*cos(ti/2)

Comment: % Manually linear interpolate
rp = find(ri <= r, 1, 'first');
rm = find(ri >= r, 1, 'last');

tp = find(ti <= t, 1, 'first');
tm = find(ti >= t, 1, 'last');

drdt = (r(rp) - r(rm)) * (t(tp) - t(tm));

dr = [r(rp)-ri  ri-r(rm)];
dt = [t(tp)-ti  ti-t(tm)];

fZ = [z(rm, tm) z(rm, tp)
      z(rp, tm) z(rp, tp)];

ZI_manual = (dr * fZ * dt.') / drdt

% Interpolate with MATLAB 
ZI_MATLAB = interp2(r, t, z', ri, ti, 'spline')

Comment: please check this example, i used two for loops, inside for loop i used condition statement, if u comment this condition statement and run the program, u'll get correct answer, after u uncomment this condition statement and run the program, u'll get wrong answer. please check it.

Comment: I can not run the program if it possible post a new question

Comment: I post this program as new post pls check it

Comment: Let us continue the discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132017/how-to-interpolate-using-in-polar-coordinate)

Comment: did you get any idea

Comment: Let us continue the discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132017/how-to-interpolate-using-in-polar-coordinate)

Comment: that i know if i need to use this condition statement for radius r, the values are getting wrong

Answer (score 2):

I dunno what you have tried, but `interp2` works just as well on polar data as it does on Cartesian. Here is some evidence:

```
% Coordinates
r = linspace(0.05, 1, 50);
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 24);

% Some synthetic data
z = sort(rand(50, 24));

% Values of interest
ri = 0.075;
ti = pi/8;

% Manually interpolate
rp = find(ri <= r, 1, 'first');
rm = find(ri >= r, 1, 'last');

tp = find(ti <= t, 1, 'first');
tm = find(ti >= t, 1, 'last');

drdt = (r(rp) - r(rm)) * (t(tp) - t(tm));

dr = [r(rp)-ri  ri-r(rm)];
dt = [t(tp)-ti  ti-t(tm)];

fZ = [z(rm, tm) z(rm, tp)
      z(rp, tm) z(rp, tp)];

ZI_manual = (dr * fZ * dt.') / drdt

% Interpolate with MATLAB 
ZI_MATLAB = interp2(r, t, z', ri, ti, 'linear')
```

Result:

```
ZI_manual =
    2.737907208525297e-002
ZI_MATLAB =
    2.737907208525298e-002
```

Comment: one conversion to rectangular is needed since for linear interpolation r and theta are not of the same scale

Comment: @rahnema1 ...what?

Comment: @rahnema1 the absolute positions and corresponding data will not change, regardless of whether you're in Cartesian or in Polar coordinates. The interpolation will change slightly however, because in Cartesian you pretend that the lines connecting the neighbors are straight, and in polar, they are curved (from a Cartesian viewpoint). What you want is up to you, but usually, the curved lines are a more accurate description of the data. Also, in Cartesian, your coordinates are not regularly spaced, meaning, you should use `TriScatterInterp` or similar. Which is totally overkill.

Comment: consider the following exaple result of two interpolation on polar and rectangular are different and the correct answer is interpolation in rectangular space `Z= reshape((1:16).',4,[]);[X Y] = meshgrid(1:4);x=2;y=2;interp2 (X,Y,Z,x,y);[T,R]=cart2pol(X,Y);[t r] = cart2pol(x,y);interp2 (R,T,Z,r,t) `

Comment: @rahnema1 1ˢᵗ, that example doesn't work. 2ⁿᵈ, that is because you create a rectangular grid, and then treat it as polar, in which case you need `TriScatterInterp`. Your situation is exactly the opposite -- you have polar data, and you should then also interpolate it in a polar sense.

Comment: ...unless you started out in Cartesian and converted to Polar somewhere along the way...

Comment: this data is gridded and `TriScatterInterp` is for scattered data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129332/discussion-between-rody-oldenhuis-and-rahnema1).

Answer (score 0):

please check this example, i used two for loops, inside for loop i used condition statement, if u comment this condition statement and run the program, u'll get correct answer, after u uncomment this condition statement and run the program, u'll get wrong answer. please check it.

```
% Coordinates
r = linspace(0.05, 1, 10);
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 8);

% Some synthetic data
%z = sort(rand(50, 24));
 z=zeros();
 for i=1:10
   for j=1:8
 if r(i)<0.5||r(i)>1
     z(i,j)=0;
 else
   z(i,j) = r(i).^3'*cos(t(j)/2);
 end
 end 
end

% Values of interest
ri = 0.55;
ti = pi/8;

% Manually interpolate
rp = find(ri <= r, 1, 'first');
rm = find(ri >= r, 1, 'last');

tp = find(ti <= t, 1, 'first');
tm = find(ti >= t, 1, 'last');

drdt = (r(rp) - r(rm)) * (t(tp) - t(tm));

dr = [r(rp)-ri  ri-r(rm)];
dt = [t(tp)-ti  ti-t(tm)];

fZ = [z(rm, tm) z(rm, tp)
      z(rp, tm) z(rp, tp)];

ZI_manual = (dr * fZ * dt.') / drdt

% Interpolate with MATLAB 
ZI_MATLAB = interp2(r, t, z', ri, ti, 'linear')
```

Result: 
    z1 =
        0.1632
    ZI_manual =
        0.1543
    ZI_MATLAB =
        0.1582